# Relative path on css background-image can't find the image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sass

I know that the path needs to be relative to the CSS file.

Developing with sass, as well using the Bones template/framework for Wordpress. The file layout is like so:

localhost/wordpress

-- wp-content

-- -- themes

-- -- -- hs-theme

-- -- -- -- library

-- -- -- -- -- css

-- -- -- -- -- -- 'style.css'

-- -- -- -- -- scss

-- -- -- -- -- -- breakpoints

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- '_1030up.scss'

-- -- -- -- -- images

-- -- -- -- -- -- 'header.jpg'

I'm modifying the header class with some code in _1030up.scss, which is getting ported to style.css.

```
.header {
  background-color: $blue;
  background-image: url(../images/header.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

However, the header image is not being displayed and the selector isn't even showing up in Firebug.

Comment: You need to go up one to the scss directory first before you can go to images.

Comment: Your CSS/SASS looks correct to me. Are you sure your theme is using /hs-theme/library/css/style.css and not /hs-theme/style.css

Comment: Have you got a link to the live site?

Comment: @KaiFeller I'm hosting it locally on xampp

Comment: @JamesKing Yes, as I can edit the background-color and it will apply it. Just the image won't show up.

Answer (score 2):

Check the path that your rendered CSS files are actually being stored in. In some app platforms, LESS or SASS will compile to some static assets folder (in the case of WP, maybe /wp-content/uploads or similar), which would affect the paths you need to set.

You can also use a root relative path, e.g., '/wp-content/themes/theme_name/images/image.jpg' instead of a directory relative path as you are now.

Comment: And you can set that path obviously as a SASS variable so you don't have to type it a million times.

Comment: Searching for 'header.jpg' did return some results in wp-content/uploads/2014, but header.jpg still exists where I want it to.

Comment: Right, header.jpg is going to be in the same spot, but if your CSS file is compiled/rendered in some other directory, the path to header.jpg is no longer "../images/header.jpg". Look at the source of source of your page and find the path to the CSS file. Paste it here if you wish and I can help further.

Comment: Actually I just figured it out, the header class was getting overwritten so I created a new class and now it works. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
background-image: url( images/header.jpg ) no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your path is correct, try putting `''` around it like so:

`background-image: url('../images/header.jpg') no-repeat;`

Comment: I agree, I think you’re just missing quotes.